# How can I solve the problem of a matrix overflowing into the margin?

Tags: margins, matrices

When I write this matrix it goes beyond the page.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_2x_6 + x_1x_3x_6 + x_1x_4x_5 + x_2x_3x_4x_5 
 +x_1x_3x_4x_5 + x_1x_5x_6 + x_2x_3x_5x_6 + x_1x_3x_5x_6 &x_1x_5x_7+x_2x_3x_5x_7+x_1x_3x_5x_7  \\
x_2x_6+ x_1x_3x_6 + x_4+x_4x_5x_6 + x_3x_4x_5x_6+ x_3x_5x_6 &  1 & x_8+x_4x_7+x_3x_5x_6x_7\\
x_1x_5x_7+x_3x_5x_7 &  x_8+x_4x_7+x_5x_6x_7 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you expect to improve the formatting? Do you want to make the font smaller? What about not printing everything (and using alternative variables instead)?

Comment: All depends on point size of document class (and class). Please provide a minimum working example. Besides that, if the presentation doesn't fit the margins, you may consider simplifying the presentation.

Comment: For the sake of the reader, a rewrite like the one Werner suggests is better it will also look cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from fitting easily on a page, the following solution has the advantage of introducing names for the expressions that allow you to refer to the expressions later on.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1  & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21}&   1   & a_{23} \\
a_{21}& a_{32} &   1   
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align*}
  a_{12} &=x_2x_6 + x_1x_3x_6 
          + x_1x_4x_5 + x_2x_3x_4x_5\\
         &\quad + x_1x_3x_4x_5 + x_1x_5x_6
          + x_2x_3x_5x_6
          + x_1x_3x_5x_6 \\
  a_{13} &=x_1x_5x_7+x_2x_3x_5x_7
          + x_1x_3x_5x_7 \\
  a_{21} &= x_2x_6+ x_1x_3x_6 + x_4
          + x_4x_5x_6 + x_3x_4x_5x_6
          + x_3x_5x_6 \\
  a_{23} &= x_8+x_4x_7+x_3x_5x_6x_7\\
  a_{31} &= x_1x_5x_7+x_3x_5x_7\\
  a_{32} &= x_8+x_4x_7+x_5x_6x_7
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I may, I would rather denote the names with capital letters (A_{12}, &c.), as lowercase looks a little too much ‘generic element’ of a matrix.

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the `aligned` environment for long entry, `\medmath` from `nccmath` (about 80 % of `\displaystyle`) and playing with `arraycolsep`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[ showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\setlength\arraycolsep{4pt}
  \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &\begin{aligned}x_2x_6 + x_1x_3x_6 + x_1x_4x_5 + x_2x_3x_4x_5 \\[-0.8ex]{}
    +x_1x_3x_4x_5+ x_1x_5x_6 + x_2x_3x_5x_6 + x_1x_3x_5x_6\end{aligned} &\begin{aligned}x_1x_5x_7+x_2x_3x_5x_7\\[-0.8ex]{}+x_1x_3x_5x_7 \end{aligned} \\[3ex]
    \begin{aligned}x_2x_6 + x_1x_3x_6 + x_4+x_4x_5x_6\\[-0.8ex] {} + x_3x_4x_5x_6+ x_3x_5x_6\end{aligned} & 1 & x_8+x_4x_7+x_3x_5x_6x_7\\[3ex]
    x_1x_5x_7+x_3x_5x_7 & x_8+x_4x_7+x_5x_6x_7 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @gernot: Congratulation for detecting my freudian slip ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Not my favourite solution, but if you want to have the expressions verbatim in the matrix and don't want to reduce the font size within the matrix compared to the surrounding text, this is a way.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\wrapped[1]%
  {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}%
   \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{array}%
  }
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1
& \wrapped
  {x_2x_6 + x_1x_3x_6\\
   {} + x_1x_4x_5 + x_2x_3x_4x_5\\
   {} +x_1x_3x_4x_5 + x_1x_5x_6\\
   {} + x_2x_3x_5x_6\\
   {} + x_1x_3x_5x_6
  }
& \wrapped
  {x_1x_5x_7+x_2x_3x_5x_7\\
   {}+x_1x_3x_5x_7
  }
\\
  \wrapped
  {x_2x_6+ x_1x_3x_6 + x_4\\
   {}+x_4x_5x_6 + x_3x_4x_5x_6\\
   {}+ x_3x_5x_6
  }
& 1
& x_8+x_4x_7+x_3x_5x_6x_7
\\
  x_1x_5x_7+x_3x_5x_7
& x_8+x_4x_7+x_5x_6x_7
& 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```